"Sleeping-pill box" : pronunciation
According to the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, the primary stresses are /ˈsleeping pill/ and /ˈpillbox/.
According to Garner, its deep morphology would still be [sleeping [[pillbox]].
So how is the compound sleeping-pill box pronounced, and why?

Obviously we don't say "the sleeping 'pillbox" because it is not the pillbox that is asleep. I would say "the 'sleeping-pill box". You are talking about sleeping-pills.

I think pretty much everyone would put the most stress on the first syllable "sleeping-pill box" but I can't claim to know the rules for this.

Such a compound might be used by an individual speaker but it lacks the features of a typical compound that has achieved widespread traction and become a word in its own right: the stresses of sleeping-pill-box are tearing it apart.  So I take issue with the question's "the compound sleeping-pill box".

"Box of sleeping pills",  or "box for sleeping pills"  would be better than sleeping-pill box.

How is is pronounced? What does that even mean?

Just maybe your search engine got confused. Don't forget that a "pillbox" is also a defensive military structure.

'Sleeping-pill box' is no 'compound'. It's simply a phrase, using a hyphenated adjective - 'sleeping-pill' to describe a noun - 'box'… which matters little.
Since 'Sleeping-pill…' as distinct from any other '… pill…' box is highly unlikely in English where does it come from?
Is 'sleeping-pill box' your own idea, or a translation from another language where it matters?
A '[sleeping [[pillbox]]' necessarily denies any understanding of the 'Sleeping-pill box…' or you can explain why!
After all that, if 'Sleeping-pill box…' was a thing in English, the emphasis would be on 'Slee…'

The principle of pronunciation for compounds is early stress.

(LPD)
1 A two-element compound is typically pronounced with early stress, that is to say, its first element has more stress than the second.

For instance, in this same dictionary "soapbox" is pronounced as follows: uk /ˈsəʊp bɒks/ us /ˈsoʊp bɑːks/.
sleeping pill (pronunciation from the Cambridge dictionary) uk /ˈsliːp ɪŋ ˌpɪl/ us /ˈsliː pɪŋ ˌpɪl/
The second stress, apparently a secondary stress, is probably what used to be called a tertiary stress (weaker than  secondary stress) in LPD, and which has been deleted in the last two editions of this dictionary (ˈBUTterₒFINgers, ˌINdeₒFENSiˈBILity).
The pronunciation of "sleeping pill box" should then be the following.

uk /ˈsliːp ɪŋ (ˌ)pɪl bɒks/ us /ˈsliː.pɪŋ (ˌ)pɪl bɑːks/


(LPD) Some expressions, grammatically compounds, are nevertheless pronounced with late stress (= as if they were phrases). Among them are compounds in which the first element names the material or ingredient of which a thing is made.
a ˌrubber ˈduck
ˌpaper ˈplates
ˌcheese ˈsandwiches
a ˌpork ˈpie
a ˌgold ˈring


And why do you say that sleeping pill has tertiary stress on pill. I don't think that's true—it's secondary stress. It is true that sleeping pill box has tertiary stress on pill, but that's only because there is now a secondary stressed syllable right next to pill.

@PeterShor No, according to LPD, the secondary stressed syllable next to "pill" is not what induces tertiatiary stress. The pattern is as in "butterfingers" (see in the answer, "BUTterₒFINgers"); in the new edition of the dictionary, as its author seems to want to neglect the small difference there is between tertiary and secondary, this accent is given as "ˌ", whereas it used to be "ₒ".

@PeterShor I should have added this: you can notice that what brings about a tertiary stress or a quasi-secondary stress, is a primary stress that is being reduced when compounding or affixing ('finger, inde'fensible).

The principle of pronunciation for compounds is early stress, yo surely mean just noun compounds...

Sure, absent contradictory context, it's "late stress" for cheese sandwiches. But not if they're being offered as an alternative to jam sandwiches, where we switch to early stress.

@GJC Yes. This principle extends to compounds of the adj-noun sort for adjectives of colour, in particular, and other adjectives; bluebottle, bluegrass, blueprint, bluebag, bluebell, bluebeard, … yellow-hammer,yellow-jacket, greenhouse, greenstone, greengrocer, greyhound, etc. However there are a few exceptions (blue-collar, blue-pencil, …).  Other adj: longbow, longboat, shortbread, shorthorn, short-order (but for the adj "short-term", late stress),… It is not true for adj of the "adv-past p. sort (well-known, well-formed, well-made, etc., long-winded, longsighted,  long-forgotten, etc.

According to Garner, its deep morphology would still be [sleeping [[pillbox]].

@GJC "Deep morphology" is not a concept familiar to me, unfortunately. The way I understand this is in term of basic combinations: there are five  terms (defined) at the root of the combination, "sleeping" (vbl n), "pill" (n), "sleeping-pill" (n), "box" (n), "pillbox" (n). The fact that there exists the term "pillbox"  does not imply that the succession of "pill" and "box" in "sleeping-pill box" has to be interpreted as rendering the term "pillbox"; in fact the succession is not quite the same (space, no space). "Pillbox" is a generic term   (1/3)

@GJC  for boxes made to contain all sorts of pills and the relation is of the type "subject, complement": "box is for pills". If we look at "sleeping-pill", the relation is "verb, adverbial" ("instrument" is the type of adverbial) and the relation can be expressed as "sleeping  with a pill, that is to say sleeping by the means of a pill". In the same way, the relation between "sleeping-pills" and the box that contains them must be the same as for "pillbox" since a sleeping-pill is nothing but a particular sort of pill. (2/3)

@GJC "Box for sleeping-pills" is the formulation, and there is no reason to look at this compound as if it contained the term "pillbox". Doing this would induce another relation between "sleeping" and "pillbox", the most obvious being "verbal noun, subject" as in  "firing squad", "washing machine", and that would make no sense, except figuratively. (3/3)

It's a 'sleeping-pill 'box or even 'sleeping-pill 'pillbox because both terms are nouns in their own right so they each get their own stress. You're in effect created a three-word compound noun this way.
A sleeping 'pillbox would be something else, a pillbox that happens to be sleeping, so the first word wouldn't be stressed.

Two primary stresses in a phrase?

Sorry I deleted my comment about the awkward phrase (in particular using pill twice) because it was itself awkward, but didn't DV.

Doesn't box (or pillbox) get secondary stress in such contexts?

@FumbleFingers Probably. I was honestly trying to avoid getting into secondary or tertiary stresses as those are too often used merely to indicate syllables with unreduced vowels.

Well, I guess if the context was you were looking for the sleeping pill box (that you forgot where you put it), rather than the single tablet that you just dropped on the floor, you'd have secondary stress on sleep and primary stress on box. But to a first approximation they both get stress. (And I'm not sure even I can contrive a context where pill gets the stress! :)
